# C++ templated, statically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, allocation

I'm trying to do something like this for a project...

`template <class N>
class MyClass
{
    float properties[N];
};`

Is there anyway to accomplish this in C++?

Comment: Not clear to me what you are expecting. An array of floats indexed by "some random class" ? - I'd say no you can't do that (but them I'm not up on the latest and greatest standards ;-). I'd say you'd need to create your own data structure for this rather relying on the native arrays.

Comment: normally i would but this is a bit performance intensive

Answer (score 5):

What you need is called *value* template parameter:

```
template <size_t N> class MyClass { float properties[N]; };
        //^^^^^^ note this
```

Now you can instantiate this class template, passing any non-negative integral value as template argument. For example,

```
MyClass<10> c1;  //N=10
MyClass<100> c1; //N=100
```

You can pass const expression also as:

```
const size_t size = 200;
MyClass<size>  c2; //N=200
```

Comment: thanks! thats what i needed for the header but now i cant get the .cpp file to compile properly, when i try and put any functions int the class MSVC is telling me "use of class template requires template argument list". any idea why?

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: How would I know what is `.cpp` file? and what does it contain?

Comment: the implementation of member functions for MyClass, like a constructor but visual studio highlights them with that error

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: Implementation of a templates should go in the header file itself, or else it wouldn't compile. So define the class template in the header file. Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible

Comment: the template is in the header, but the matching cpp files is giving me the error

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: Did you define the member functions in the header file? What is "matching" cpp files?

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible

Comment: so the only way to do it is to write the functions right into the header?

Comment: @DavidCarpenter: Yes. That is simple!