# reference error

Tags: c++, reference

I have a header in which I declare a function. Then I create the function and try to use it but i get an error. It is by reference but I don't know why it is not working.

struct.h

```
#ifndef LISTSTRUC_H_
#define LISTSTRUC_H_


template <class T> struct Array{
    int days;
    T * M;

Array( int size ) : days(size), M(new T[size])
{
}
~Array()
{
   delete[] M;
}
};

void currentDay();

template <class Expe>
void dummyData(Array<Expe> &);

#endif /* LISTSTRUC_H_ */
```

struct.cpp

```
void dummyData(Array <Expe> &A){
for(int i=0; i<31; i++){
    A.M[i].Expe::setObj((i*3),(i*1),(i*6),(i*2),(i*4),(i*5));
}
 }
```

M.cpp(Main cpp)

```
int main(){
//Main function of the program. no pre/ post condition.

    Array <Expe> A(31);   // Work space
    Array <Expe> B(31);   // Backup space

    dummyData(&A);         // error
 }
```

ERROR:

```
..\M.cpp:22:14: error: no matching function for call to 'dummyData(Array<Expe>*)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dummyData(&A);
```

should be:

```
dummyData(A);
```

**Rationale:**
Your function takes a reference not a pointer, `&A` means you are passing address of the type which can only be received in by a pointer to that type and you don't have that overloaded version of the function, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

If passing object by reference, don't pass its address, like you did here:

```
dummyData(&A);
```

Just pass the object itself (as reference is its alias):

```
dummyData(A);
```

Comment: changed dummyData(A); but still D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../M.cpp:22: undefined reference to `void dummyData<Expe>(Array<Expe>&)'

Comment: @BogdanMaier That's a whole other question, which is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible

Comment: you need to move template function implementation to header file, as Rob noticed + in `main()` you need to state exact type instead of `Expe`, which is just the name of the template parameter

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put reference `&` to pass a variable by reference, simply pass it.

```
dummyData(A);
```

Passing by reference means that you are not copying the object, instead you are using the object itself and, if passed as variable (not `const`) changes will affect it.

Comment: changed dummyData(A);
D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../M.cpp:22: undefined reference to `void dummyData<Expe>(Array<Expe>&)'

Comment: Have you `#include`d the file in which `dummyData` is declared?

Comment: in M.cpp i have includet 
#include "Expe.h"
#include "ListStruc.h"

Comment: How about `#include "struct.h"`?

Comment: struct.h = listStruc.h ... my bad when wrote the post

Answer (score 1):

```
dummyData(&A);
```

should be

```
dummyData(A);
```

The `&` operator in this context is taking the address of `A` which is a pointer. To pass a reference you just use the actual variable name.

Comment: changed dummyData(A); but still D:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5_OOP\Debug/../M.cpp:22: undefined reference to `void dummyData<Expe>(Array<Expe>&)'