# C++ Generic Linked List Separate Class

Tags: c++, templates, generics, data-structures, linked-list

Ive been working on a `linked list` implementation. Previously i had it working for only `char` as the data type. I tried implementing generics/templates so i could use any data type.

I have 4 files in my project. `Clist.h, Clist.cpp, Main.cpp and EmptyListException.h`.

Previously my program would not run when i had my `Clist.cpp` seperate from my `Main.cpp`. I then copied the entire class too my `Main.cpp` and it runs without a problem.

Is there a way i can do this so my `Clist.cpp` can be separate from my main file (which is a test harness for the `linked list`).

I can post the code if it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For templates to work, they can't be separated between a *.h file and *.cpp file. The compiler needs to see the implementation of the template to use it.

See this similar question: [Splitting templated C++ classes into .hpp/.cpp files--is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible)

Comment: So i technically don't need Clist.cpp if i add all the code from Clist.cpp to my Main.cpp

Comment: Yes, but it would probably be better to move the templated code from `Clist.cpp` to `Clist.h` to prevent your `Main.cpp` from getting cluttered. For example, if you see the implementation of the standard vector library, all the generic code is in one header file.