# c++ template usage with member function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

The below simply does not compile and I cannot fix it.
Hope a good soul can make me understand how to fix this example.

thanks in

I try to compile:

```
# make
g++    -c -o client.o client.cpp
client.cpp: In function `int main()':
client.cpp:7: error: missing template arguments before "t"
client.cpp:7: error: expected `;' before "t"
client.cpp:8: error: `t' undeclared (first use this function)
client.cpp:8: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
<builtin>: recipe for target `client.o' failed
make: *** [client.o] Error 1
```

client.cpp - the main

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Test.h"
#include"Other.h"

int main() {

        Test<Other> t = Test<Other>(&Other::printOther);
        t.execute();

        return 0;
}
```

Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include"Other.h"

template<typename T> class Test {

        public:
                Test();
                Test(void(T::*memfunc)());
                void execute();

        private:
                void(T::*memfunc)(void*);
};

#endif
```

Test.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Test.h"
#include"Other.h"


Test::Test() {
}

Test::Test(void(T::*memfunc)()) {
        this->memfunc= memfunc;
}

void Test::execute() {
        Other other;
        (other.*memfunc)();
}
```

Other.h

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

class Other {
        public:
                Other();
                void printOther();
};

#endif
```

Other.cpp

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Other.h"


Other::Other() {
}

void Other::printOther() {
        printf("Other!!\n");
}
```

Makefile

```
all: main

main: client.o Test.o Other.o
        g++ -o main $^

clean:
        rm *.o

run:
        ./main.exe
```

The Makefile will allow easy compiling.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately [it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2143606/493122) to write the implementation of a template class into a cpp file (even though [there is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1724632/493122) if you know exactly what types you are going to use). Template class and functions should be declared and implemented inside the header file.

You have to move the implementation of `Test` inside its header file.

Comment: Not true ... see Benoît's answer at your link.

Comment: @JimBalter, I was right about to edit my answer to insert that option as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix:
move the definition of the function in Test.cpp inline into the class in Test.h

The definition of the member function of the template class have to be in the **same compiler-unit**. Usually in the same .h where the class is defined. If you don’t made inline into the class the function’s definition, and want there only the declaration, you will need to add before the definition (well as part of the definition) of each function the "magic" words `template<typename T>`. This is only an approximately answer to give you the direction to revise the reference doc, and some examples.