# Classic Linker Mach error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, adt, mach-o

I don't know C++ very well and I'm teaching myself about ADT's and data structures. Unfortunately every time I need to compile the code I get the classic xcode error: mach link error. I tend to understand these errors when they're in objective-c (because it usually means that I'm missing a file). I made sure to add the file to my target to avoid this issue, but that didn't seem to work. Neither did the classic turn Xcode on and off trick.

Below is the error and code:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ArrayBag<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::getIndexOf(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
      ArrayBag<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::remove(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in main.o
  "ArrayBag<int>::getIndexOf(int const&) const", referenced from:
      ArrayBag<int>::remove(int const&) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

#ifndef _ARRAY_BAG
#define _ARRAY_BAG
#include "BagInterface.h"
#include <vector>


template<class ItemType>
class ArrayBag : public BagInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 24; // the bag size a bit bigger to allow
                                            // adding bags.
    ItemType items[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];      // Array of bag items
    int itemCount;                         // Current count of bag items
    int maxItems;                          // Max capacity of the bag

    // Returns either the index of the element in the array items that
    // contains the given target or -1, if the array does not contain
    // the target.
    int getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;

public:
    ArrayBag();
    int getCurrentSize() const;
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool add(const ItemType& newEntry);
    void clear();
    bool remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
    bool contains(const ItemType& target) const;
    int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
    ArrayBag<string> merge(ArrayBag<string> a, ArrayBag<string> b);
    std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const;





#include "ArrayBag.h"
#include <cstddef>

template<class ItemType>
ArrayBag<ItemType>::ArrayBag(): itemCount(0), maxItems(DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
{
}  // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getCurrentSize() const
{
    return itemCount;
}  // end getCurrentSize

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return itemCount == 0;
}  // end isEmpty

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    bool hasRoomToAdd = (itemCount < maxItems);
    if (hasRoomToAdd)
    {
        items[itemCount] = newEntry;
        itemCount++;
    }  // end if

    return hasRoomToAdd;
}  // end add

template<class ItemType>
void ArrayBag<ItemType>::clear()
{
    itemCount = 0;
}  // end clear

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::remove(const ItemType& anEntry)
{
    int locatedIndex = getIndexOf(anEntry);
    bool canRemoveItem = !isEmpty() && (locatedIndex > -1);
    if (canRemoveItem)
    {
        itemCount--;
        items[locatedIndex]=items[itemCount];
    }//end if
    return canRemoveItem;
} //end remove

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayBag<ItemType>::contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    bool found = false;
    int curIndex = 0; //current array index
    while(!found && (curIndex < itemCount))
    {
        if(anEntry == items[curIndex])
        {
            found = true;
        } //end if

        curIndex++; //increment to the next entry
    } //end while
    return found;
}

template<class ItemType>
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const
{
    int frequency = 0;
    int curIndex = 0; //current index array
    while(curIndex < itemCount)
    {
        if (items[curIndex] == anEntry)
        {
            frequency++;
        } //end if

        curIndex++; //incremenet to next entry
    } //end while
    return frequency;
} //end getFrequencyOf


template<class ItemType>
vector<ItemType> ArrayBag<ItemType>::toVector() const
{
    vector<ItemType> bagContents;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        bagContents.push_back(items[i]);

    return bagContents;
}  // end toVector

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArrayBag.h"
#include "ArrayBag.cpp"

using namespace std;

void displayBag(ArrayBag<string>& bag)
{
    cout << "The bag contains " << bag.getCurrentSize()
    << " items:" << endl;
    vector<string> bagItems = bag.toVector();
    int numberOfEntries = (int)bagItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
    {
        cout << bagItems[i] << " ";
    }  // end for
    cout << endl << endl;
}  // end displayBag

void displayBag(ArrayBag<int>& bag)
{
    cout << "The bag contains " << bag.getCurrentSize()
    << " items:" << endl;
    vector<int> bagItems = bag.toVector();
    int numberOfEntries = (int)bagItems.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
    {
        cout << bagItems[i] << " ";
    }  // end for
    cout << endl << endl;
}  // end displayBag

int sumOfBag(ArrayBag<int>& aBag)
{
    int sum=0;
    vector<int> aBagvector = aBag.toVector();
    int numberOfEntries = (int) aBagvector.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++)
    {
        sum += aBagvector[i];
    }
    //cout << "The sum of the bag is " << sum << endl;
    return sum;
}

void bagTester(ArrayBag<string>& bag)
{
    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << bag.isEmpty()
    << "; should be 1 (true)" << endl;
    displayBag(bag);

    string items[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "one"};
    cout << "Add 6 items to the bag: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        bag.add(items[i]);
    }  // end for

    displayBag(bag);

    cout << "isEmpty: returns " << bag.isEmpty()
    << "; should be 0 (false)" << endl;

    cout << "getCurrentSize: returns " << bag.getCurrentSize()
    << "; should be 6" << endl;

    cout << "Try to add another entry: add(\"extra\") returns "
    << bag.add("extra") << endl;
    displayBag(bag);
} // end bagTester


int main()
{
    ArrayBag<string> bag;
    cout << "Testing the Array-Based Bag:" << endl;
    cout << "The initial bag is empty." << endl;
    bagTester(bag);
    ArrayBag<string> bag_of_strings1;
    string items[] = {"tom","dick","harry"};
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {bag_of_strings1.add(items[i]);}
    displayBag(bag_of_strings1);
    ArrayBag<string> bag_of_strings2;
    string new_items[] = {"now","is","the","time","for","all"};
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        bag_of_strings2.add(new_items[i]);
    }
    displayBag(bag_of_strings2);
    //ArrayBag<string> newbag=merge(bag_of_strings1,bag_of_strings2);

    //displayBag(newbag);

    ArrayBag<int> bag_of_ints;
    int array_of_ints[]={6,7,85,9,12,15};
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
        bag_of_ints.add(array_of_ints[i]);
    }
    displayBag(bag_of_ints);
    cout<<sumOfBag(bag_of_ints)<<endl;

    return 0;
} // end main
```

Comment: You are including a .cpp file in what I assume is your main.cpp. How is your project or whatever in Xcode set up?

Comment: I did. I have a Arraybag.h file and a Arraybag.cpp file. I assumed that the .cpp file was the issue, but as soon as I removed it I received a host of errors. (linker errors)

Comment: .cpps are compilation units and need to be compiled separately, then linked. You should never `#include` them. Your project setup is the problem.

Comment: I did remove the .cpp file but I'm still receiving a host of errors.

Comment: You should keep all the code for your ArrayBag template class in a single header file, and delete ArrayBag.cpp. You don't need it. I think the problem you have though is that there is no implementation for ArrayBag<ItemType>::getIndexOf in your code.

Comment: All my code is separated into separate files. I just poorly pasted it into Stack Overflow. I can redo it.

Comment: I don't think you understand. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker is telling you there is no implementation for  ArrayBag::getIndexOf. The implementation is also missing from your code dump. Try adding this:

```
int ArrayBag<ItemType>::getIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const
{
    // TODO
    return 0;
}
```

Unlike normal classes, template classes should be defined in a single header file without a corresponding .cpp file.