# How to define the constructor of an inner template class of another template class?

Tags: c++, templates

I have an inner template class of another template class:

```
// hpp file
template< class T1 > class C1
{
   // ...
public:
   // ...
   C1();
   template< class T2 > C2
   {
      // ...
      C2();
   };
};
```

When I declare the inner class constructor I get some errors:

```
//cpp file
template<> C1< MyType >::C1()
{
   // ...
}

template<> template< class T2 > C1< MyType >::C2::C2() // error: invalid use of template-name ‘class C1<MyType>::C2’ without an argument list    
{
   // ...
}
```

I have also tried :

```
template<> template< class T2 > C1< MyType >::C2<T2>::C2() // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class C1<MyType>::C2<T2>’
{
   // ...
}
```

Incomplete type, but constructor has no type...

I am a little stuck here. How to declare it?

Comment: template<class T1> template< class T2> ...

Comment: First off [You cannot split a template class in a .hpp file and .cpp file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible)

Comment: Are you trying to specialize the inner class as well?

Comment: No, I am not trying to specialize the inner class as well, is that the problem? Why? :)

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that you can split it if there is a specialization... So that is why i shall specialize also the inner class?

Comment: The usage of `template<>` and `C1<MyType` is confusing and I was curiuos if you were trying to  perform a specialization of some kind.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do a specialization for MyType, but I am not specialising the inner class; is that the problem?

Comment: You (all) are right, I shall define the inner class' members in the header...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the following:

```
template<typename T1>
template<typename T2>
C1<T1>::C2<T2>::C2()
{
}
```

Comment: That is it, but why is it not working for a specialization?

Comment: @sop What are you trying to specialize?

Comment: @sop You should verify this but if you specialize the outer class I'm pretty sure you need to specialize the inner class as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specialize the outer class by defining an inner template class's method. If you want to specialize both the inner class and outer class, you can:

```
template<>
template<> 
C1<MyType>::C2<char>::C2()
{
   // ...
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/DQCSUI93979)

If you want to keep the inner class generic, you should specialize the outer class first:

```
template<> 
class C1<MyType>
{
   // ...
public:
   // ...
   C1();
   template< class T2 > class C2
   {
      public:
      // ...
      C2();
   };
};
```

and then define the constructor of `C2` like,

```
template<class T2> 
C1<MyType>::C2<T2>::C2()
{
   // ...
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/QQZVF59596)

Comment: Well I have another question then: what does `template< class T = MyClass > class C1 {};` means? Isn't it a specialization?

Comment: @sop It's another definition of `C1`, so you'll get a redefinition error. `class T = MyClass` means `MyClass` is the default template parameter, so you can use it like `C1<> c1`, but it's not specialization.