# macOS and CMake - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, cmake

When running

```
cmake --build . --config Release --clean-first
```

on macOS for my code located [here](https://github.com/marco1893/linalglib) I obtain

```
Scanning dependencies of target LinAlg
[ 20%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/LinAlg.dir/source/cmatrix.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object lib/CMakeFiles/LinAlg.dir/source/cvector.cpp.o
[ 60%] Linking CXX static library libLinAlg.a
warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: warning for library: libLinAlg.a the table of contents is empty (no object file members in the library define global symbols)
[ 60%] Built target LinAlg
Scanning dependencies of target main
[ 80%] Building CXX object main/CMakeFiles/main.dir/source/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "LinAlg::Vector::CVector<float>::show()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
  "LinAlg::Vector::CVector<float>::CVector(unsigned long)", referenced     from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
  "LinAlg::Vector::CVector<float>::~CVector()", referenced from:
  _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: Fehler: ld gab 1 als Ende-Status zurück
make[2]: *** [main/main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I searched for a hour now, but I have no clue what is going wrong. Can someone help?

Thank you.

PS: I did not post all my code here, because I don't want to overload the post.

Comment: This is due to splitting templates between .h and .cpp files: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible

Comment: So long story short: I should do the implementation of my functions in my .h files?

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct.

Comment: It works, thank you.