# Using a template for a stack implementation; "name followed by :: must be a class or namespace"

Tags: c++

*stack.h*

```
template <class DataType>
class Stack {
private:
    int * topPtr;
public:
    Stack();    //constructor; initializes top to nullptr
    void push();    //adds a node
    void pop();     //removes most recently added node
};
```

And *stack.cpp* thus far:

```
#include "stack.h"
//using namespace std;
template <class DataType>
Stack::Stack() {
    topPtr = nullptr;
}
```

It is the `Stack::` that is underlined with the error "name followed by :: must be a class or namespace." If relevant, I am using VS Code.

I would just like to have a generic stack implementation, and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the error message verbatim.

Comment: " I would just like to have a generic stack implementation" that is [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)

Comment: What's wrong with [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack)?

Comment: Before you go any further … you cannot (usually) split up templates into .cpp and .h files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting templated C++ classes into .hpp/.cpp files--is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724036/splitting-templated-c-classes-into-hpp-cpp-files-is-it-possible)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice That would lead to a linker error, not a compiler error like the OP is paraphrasing.

Comment: sorry for being super picky, but questions are nice question when they actually contain a question. Most of us are no native english speakers, but I have the feeling you could do better than putting a `?` at the end of something that isnt a question.

Comment: @NathanOliver it sounds like the OP is getting an error in the IDE before even compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of out of class definition is:

```
template <class DataType>
Stack<DataType>::Stack() : topPtr{nullptr} {}
//    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Somehow I missed that syntax while looking at my reference.

Comment: But as state in comment, you will probably have other issues as you put template definitions in cpp.

Comment: So I should move the implementation to the header file; is that correct?

Comment: Yes. template definitions should be inline.